Hardfault handler in pico-sdk
I'm encountering a hardfault issue with my Raspberry Pi Pico SDK project. My controller gets stuck in a hardfault state, and I am unsure how to handle it properly. Ideally, I would expect the controller to reset itself after a hardfault, but instead, it remains stuck, requiring a manual reset to resume operation.
Here are some details of my setup:
Device: Raspberry Pi Pico W
Development Environment: Arduino IDE 2.0
SDK Version: Raspberry Pi Pico SDK 1.5.1
Debugging Tool: Official Raspberry Pi Debug Probe
Has anyone else faced a similar issue, or does anyone know of an implementation of isr_hardfault in the Raspberry Pi Pico SDK that I can utilize to handle this more effectively? Any insights or suggestions on resolving this would be greatly appreciated.
My major concern is regarding the IMPLEMENTATION OF HARDFAULT HANDLER IN PICO-SDK .
Thank you!
I used Official Raspberry Pi Debug Probe in Arduino ide 2.0 to debug my code . It is providing me with the below given logs .
hardfault error log
I am expecting the controller to reset itself while encountering hardfault.

I have a similar issue. My program runs fine if I don't give it an input interrupt to handle during a "trial" time. Outside a trial the ISR works perfectly. Without the interrupt, the trial code works perfectly. If I give it a "lick" during the trial then it hangs in the midst of a series of USB outputs.
I was very careful not to have race conditions or proc0 stepping on proc1's toes or vv. (At least I know about these issues and tried very hard. 30+ years of real time programming, managed lots of issues over the years but this one has me stumped.
I'm looking for an expert in Pico using both processors with interrupts on just one.
I'm happy to share my code if anyone wants a look.
gperry (at) wustl.edu
